# Cakephp 3.0 - executing AppController::beforeFilter() in case of MissingRouteException

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In my app, I define (among other things) the locale based on user's preference stored in cookie if any, or by using his browser's settings. All of this is done in AppController::beforeFilter().

Problem: for 404 errors thrown by a missing route exception, the request doesn't event reach the controller. So my error400.ctp template is not rendered with the correct locale.

So defining the locale in AppController::beforeFilter may not be the best practice. Any idea where I should do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put the logic in a `DispatcherFilter`:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/dispatch-filters.html

You can take a look at this one for inspiration:

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Routing/Filter/LocaleSelectorFilter.php